# Azure Pipelines NugetCommand Task failing with error - Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 5.0.2 is not compatible with net50

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, .net-5

I've a .NET 5.0 WebApi solution and I'm trying to create a build pipeline using yml file. I'm using our Agent Pool which has a Windows agent with following capabilities.

OS: Windows_NT -> OSArchitecture: X64 -> Installed .NET 5 SDK also in the agent

Here is my yml file.

```
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: sdk
    version: 5.x

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'NuGet Installer'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 5.x

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
```

But this is throwing tons of errors in "NuGetCommand" task such as

```
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1202: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 5.0.2 is not compatible with net50 (.NETFramework,Version=v5.0). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 5.0.2 supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)
NU1202: Package Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 5.0.2 is not compatible with net50 (.NETFramework,Version=v5.0). Package Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 5.0.2 supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)
NU1202: Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core 3.21.1 is not compatible with net50 (.NETFramework,Version=v5.0). Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core 3.21.1 supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow steps about it:

**1)** try to use `noCache: true` under nuget restore task:

```
steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    noCache: true
```

**2)** Instead, you could use [dotnet restore task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/packages/nuget-restore?view=azure-devops#restore-nuget-packages-with-the-net-core-cli-task) with `no cache:true` to restore your project.

**Besides**, if this does not work, please share the whole csproj file with us to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: NoCache didn't work. Dotnet restore task works but it's taking longer time to execute. The build which is supposed to finish in 5 mins, now takes around 19 mins if I use dotnet restore using "our agent pool". It works faster with "windows-latest" pool though, but then our SonarQube task will not work (token error). Here is the main project's project file contents. `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"><PropertyGroup>   <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework></PropertyGroup><ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.17.0" />`

Comment: Please check if you select the right branch about your project, Second, not sure why the latest nuget.exe does not work, or you could declare the specific version of the nuget.exe under `NuGetToolInstaller` task, use `5.9.1` or another `5.7.1`.  You could also add `system.debug :true` to check the detailed restore log.

Comment: Also, since the error  and your csproj file, there is no reference to `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL`, make sure that all the projects are under  the same branch. Besdies, make sure you checked nuget.org and did not use other `nuget.config` file.

Comment: I'd to remove Npgsql reference when I posted because of comment-text limit. I didn't have any other config file. Let me chck with system.debug: true.

Comment: I finally used our agent pool and used DotNetCoreCLI@2 tasks. Now it built successfully, but took around 20 mins. Then I removed **/*.csproj from the Dotnet Build task (projects attribute) and just gave that task. It executed much faster. It still built all projects. Do we really need to give `projects: '**/*.csproj'`?

Comment: If you did not input anything, that also is also equal to `**/*.csproj`, that is quite strange. Did you try to use `*.sln`? How many projects do you want to restore? `**\*.csproj` will catch all csproj files to restore, if you only need one file to restore, you could use the full name of csproj file. Also, check your private agent's connection and you could run `run.bat` to update the agent.